# How can Gröbner bases used to describe discrete probability?

Tags: probability, maple

[Cross post from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8830/2949), figured this community may be more relevant]

I am working in the field of machine learning, and I have come across a few papers that show relationships between Gröbner bases and discrete probability. So I come here for help.

Can you please explain how can Gröbner bases used to describe discrete probability?

I have looked at Gröbner bases and I understand the general concepts (and used Maple to calculate a few examples). So it is the link that is missing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper

http://www.ricam.oeaw.ac.at/Groebner-Bases-Bibliography/gbbib_files/publication_582.pdf

by Pistone et al seems to be the source paper for this.